# Filtering a django queryset based on a MTM field

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a very lightweight crm for a non-profit, in django.  The models of interest to this problem are:

```
class Human(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        namestring = self.last_name+','+self.first_name
        if self.nickname:
            namestring += '('+self.nickname+')'
        elif self.middle_name:
            namestring += '('+self.middle_name+')'
        return namestring

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    humans = models.ManyToManyField(Human, through='HumanToPhoneNumber')
    nation_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    area_code = models.IntegerField()
    local_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        what_to_call_it = "("+str(self.area_code)+")"+str(self.local_number)
        if (self.nation_code):
            what_to_call_it = str(self.nation_code)+what_to_call_it
        return what_to_call_it


class HumanToPhoneNumber(models.Model):
    human = models.ForeignKey(Human)
    phone_number = models.ForeignKey(PhoneNumber)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField('begin date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField('end date', null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    preferred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        what_to_call_it = str(self.human)
        if self.label:
            what_to_call_it += "("+self.label+")"
        return what_to_call_it
```

When I show the phone numbers for a person, I only want to show the ones that are still "active", and also display a marker by the preferred method of contact (there are similar models for email, humantoemail, address, humantoaddress).  More than one person can have the same number, and a person can have multiple numbers, so it's many-to-many.

The view for this is:

```
def human(request, human_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Human, pk=human_id)
    emails = p.emailaddress_set.all()
    emails.filter(emailaddress__humantoemailaddress.active=True) #this line does not work
    phone_numbers = p.phonenumber_set.all()
    addresses = p.physicaladdress_set.all()    
    return render_to_response('person.html', {'person': p, 'emails': emails, 'phone_numbers': phone_numbers, 'addresses': addresses})
```

I've tried a few variations on the above, but I'm clearly not groking how I'm meant to access the "active" field on the many-to-many relationship.  I can't put the field on the Email, PhoneNumber, or PhysicalAddress model because it could be still active for one person but no longer active for another, and similarly for "preferred".

What is the right way to write this query in a django view?  Any help is appreciated.  Oh, and I'm using Django 1.3, in case that matters.

Edit: corrected a typo in the above, plus tried a different filter on phone number copied more or less exactly from Django docs on MTM:

```
def human(request, human_id):
p = get_object_or_404(Human, pk=human_id)
emails = p.emailaddress_set.filter(humantoemailaddress__active=True) <--- does not work
phone_numbers = p.phone_number_set.filter(humantophonenumber__begin_date__gt=date(2011,1,1)) <--- does not work either
addresses = p.physicaladdress_set.all()    
return render_to_response('person.html', {'person': p, 'emails': emails, 'phone_numbers': phone_numbers, 'addresses': addresses})
```

Any help is appreciated, and let me know if there's any other details I should be adding.

Second Edit: D'oh!  It helps to edit the right file.  I have checked the answer below, which actually works just fine.

Comment: There is a typo, emailaddress__humantoemailaddress.active should be emailaddress__humantoemailaddress__active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on fields in the joining table using double underscore notation e.g. `humantophonenumber__active`.

For example:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Human, pk=human_id)
phone_numbers = p.phone_number_set.filter(humantophonenumber__active=True)
```

For further Beatles-based examples, check out the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).